# Flutter text overflow in Android emulator, works fine in IOS emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Column widget that has 2 children: a SizedBox and a Container with a Text widget. I get an overflow in iOS emulator, but it renders without problems on Android. Should I be using MediaQuery to customize the SizedBox height based on type of device? (NOTE: The Scaffold/Stack code is included merely to provide more context, and likely has no bearing on the overflow issue, unless I'm mistaken!)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Swiper(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragStart: (details) {
            /* do something */
            ));
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
              return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      end: Alignment.center,
                      colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.white])
                  .createShader(bounds);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding:
                  new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage(tipList[index].imagePath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              new SizedBox(height: 700),
              Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Text(tipList[index].description,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image: Screenshot of iOS vs Android emulators]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your text with Positioned:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Swiper(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragStart: (details) {
            /* do something */
            ));
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
              return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      end: Alignment.center,
                      colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.white])
                  .createShader(bounds);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding:
                  new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage(tipList[index].imagePath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            child:
              Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Text(tipList[index].description,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Worked, with a minor addition: I set the left and right constraints in Position, else it ignores the Container right/left padding and text rolls off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use FittedBox with BoxFit.scaleDown and I update your code.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Swiper(
          itemCount: tipList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragStart: (details) {},
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  ShaderMask(
                    shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                      return const LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              end: Alignment.center,
                              colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.white])
                          .createShader(bounds);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(tipList[index].imagePath),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 700),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
                        child: FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                          child: Text(tipList[index].description,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This worked, but due to the "scale down" effect, when the user swipes, every image in the carousel appears with a different sized caption (depending on the length of the caption).

Answer (score 0):

It is because height of these 2 screens are different. In order to make it UI responsive, you should avoid using SizedBox or Containers with exact height and use Expanded/Spacer widget. Both of this widgets will take maximum available space on that specific device screen.
So I would try first with this:

```dart
   Column(
            children: [
              Spacer(), //or Expanded(child:Container()),
              Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Text(tipList[index].description,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Neither Spacer nor Expanded worked, the text appears right at the top of the screen.